# Capturing image with webcam

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a project with Asp.net MVC4.  I need to take pictures with a webcam. This application should be configurable with any tablet.
Currently runs the application on desktop, on tablets no.

I am using jscam.swf and jscam_canvas_only.swf.

On tablets I use this the Samsung Galaxy on these devices install adobe flash player to a well does not work ... someone knows some other technology to take pictures or if someone can help me solve this problem I'll be grateful

Comment: I shudder at the thought of web apps having access to my webcam.

Comment: Hi Graham Why would you shudder at the thought on web apps having access to webcam? What is the problem?

Comment: Security. If you can do it with user permission, then you can probably do it covertly. Web apps should never, never have access to any component other than the browser, in my opinion. Think about how much trouble ActiveX controls caused when malicious sites started using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Latest method as of 2020

```js
const userVideo = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
const userVideoTrack = userVideo.getVideoTracks()[0]
const photoBlob = await new ImageCapture(userVideoTrack).takePhoto()
```

You can then proceed the blob with something like the `FileReader` or `URL` API.

Answer (score 6):

Flash has limited support on Android tablets and no support on iOS devices.

A better solution may be to move to 100% HTML5.  When using HTML5, your browser has access to your webcam.  Below are some links showing HTML5 accessing your webcam:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/
- http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/06/html5/filtering-a-webcam-using-getusermedia-and-html5-canvas
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/navigator.getUserMedia

Comment: hi @MattHouser excellent links, I add Html5 in a test project, I can capture the desktop image but the tablets I get the following message:
getUserMedia() not support in your browser.
In my tablet samsung I download chrome browser
Can you help with this problem and enable getUserMedia () in tablets?

Comment: According to this chart (http://mobilehtml5.org/), `getUserMedia()` is only available on BB10, Opera, and Chrome only (but only when enabling an experimental flag).  For Chrome, try using `webkitGetUserMedia()`.  You may find you have very limited resources to access the webcam.  Support may just not be there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Silverlight? Since you are using .NET this might be helpful. http://elegantcode.com/2009/11/20/silverlight-4-webcam-a-quick-glance/

SL is a simple plugin it runs on every browser, you just need to embed your Silverlight component within your view code and the browser will handle it as an object tag.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Silverlight is not supported on iPads and Android tablets.

Comment: Well I didn´t know that one. Then I´m thinking in something written in HTML 5 but you know that could be a huge pain in the butt..

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to enable the camera and audio using HTML5 Chrome using Android for tablets.
We connect to chrome://flags/ and look for WebRTC. 
After we enable this flag. 
Restart the browser or tablet and working properly.